# add variable number of empty columns to a tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix with a column group so that it will create a column for that field provided any row has data for that column.

[image: tablix]

I need to create a version of this report that contains some empty columns on the end.
I want the number of columns to be added to be based on some factor of the non empty columns with some min/max constraints also. (my question is not how to get the number of columns required)

so far i've tried.
1 - adding individual empty columns to the tablix and setting the visibility condition on each column.

a bit long winded and a bit of a faff.

2 - creating another column group and grouping on the same field, this creates

cant vary the number of columns returned.

am i missing a simple way of adding x empty rows or columns to a tablix? where x can be calculated somehow from the values in the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to fib this scenario in your data. The column-wise grouping works with known data including those falling in the column group value with null values. There is no way to grow your groups without data unless you add some column group footer logic that would be pretty weird.

I would look into producing phantom NULL value records that will push out your columns.

Comment: not the solution i was looking for but provides more flexibility than what i'd already tried. thanks